# BOM or \xFF\xFE displays &#65279; in csv file

Tags: php, csv

Need to convert array to display in csv file

Here is sample code

```
$output=array(
array('firstname' => 'latviešu', 'lastname' => 'Johnson', 'age' => 25),
array('firstname' => 'русский', 'lastname' => 'latviešu', 'age' => 25),
array('firstname' => 'šAmanda', 'lastname' => 'Miller', 'age' => 18),
array('firstname' => 'english', 'lastname' => 'русский', 'age' => 25.04),
);

header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-type: application/x-msexcel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename="utf8_bom.xls"');

foreach($output as $row) {
$implode = (implode("\t", $row)). "\r\n" ;
$implode = mb_convert_encoding($implode, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 
echo $implode = "\xFF\xFE" . $implode;
}
```

csv output is like this

[image]

As you see starting from the second row there is character before each word. When I copied the character in html get `&#65279;`.

If remove `\xFF\xFE`, no such character, but the text is not normally readable. Tried to `trim`, but also not normally readable.

How to remove that character?

**Solution**

Here is solution finally

```
foreach($output as $row) {
if(!$flag) {
$implode = (implode("\t", array_keys($row))). "\r\n" ;
$implode = mb_convert_encoding($implode, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 
echo $implode = "\xFF\xFE" . $implode;
$flag = true;
}
$implode = (implode("\t", array_values($row))). "\r\n" ;
$implode = mb_convert_encoding($implode, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 
echo $implode;
}
```

But next question related with the code...

At the end of the array `array('firstname' => 'english', 'lastname' => 'русский', 'age' => 25.04),` is `25.04`; however in csv get `25.Apr`

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, I realize. But what is a solution... If not to echo `\xFF\xFE` , text is not readable. If to echo, get that character...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block of UTF-16 encoded text needs to start with a BOM. The BOM must not be repeated in the text itself. You're currently outputting a BOM for every single line. Don't do that, just output it once at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Oh, thank you!!! Almost all this day tried to get solution. OH. I will post working code. By the way the next problem.... in array `'age' => 25.04`, but in output 25.Apr. How to fix it?

Comment: You mean **how Excel interprets "25.04"**?

Comment: Yes, if I would understand how Excel interprets 25.04 it would be useful to think how to get solution....

Comment: No idea. I hate Excel with a passion. Search around, I'm pretty sure I've seen this discussed before. :)

Comment: Thanks:) I must use Excel/csv... coding accounting software and it is necessary to be able to export to excel

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the BOM just at the start of the file, but `mb_convert_encoding` adds it at each line. If possible, try this:

```
$utf = '';

foreach($output as $row) {
    $utf .= (implode("\t", $row)). "\r\n" ;
}

$utf = mb_convert_encoding($implode, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 
echo $utf;
```